# jquery dirty record, would like the jquery ui modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using [this](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms) to test if a form is dirty.
It defaults to the standard browser confirmation asking if you are sure you want to navigate away from this page.  On the jquery dirtyforms site it has a section that says you can use the jquery ui modal form.

So I tried adding a section (a div) like so:

```
 <div id="unsavedChanges" title="Save Changes?">
            <p>You've made changes to this page. Do you want to leave this page without saving?</p>
        </div>
```

And then I added what their code looked like:

```
 $.DirtyForms.dialog = {
        selector: '#unsavedChanges',
        fire: function(message, dlgTitle) {
            $('#unsavedChanges').dialog({ title: dlgTitle, width: 350, modal: true });
            $('#unsavedChanges').html(message);
        },
        bind: function() {
            $('#unsavedChanges').dialog('option', 'buttons',
                [
                    {
                        text: "Stay Here",
                        click: function(e) {
                            $.DirtyForms.choiceContinue = false;
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Leave This Page",
                        click: function(e) {
                            $.DirtyForms.choiceContinue = true;
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                ]
            ).bind('dialogclose', function(e) {
                // Execute the choice after the modal dialog closes
                $.DirtyForms.choiceCommit(e);
            });
        },
        refire: function(content) {
            return false;
        },
        stash: function() {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Although I am not sure where they want me to place that (I originally placed it outside of `document.ready`.  However, after running this and making a change to my form and navigating away I see that it still is using the browser confirmation instead of jquery ui dialog box.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: hmmmm.  Just reading through the documentation, I get the sense this is kind of old since he's referenceing jquery 1.4.2 and 1.7.2.  Both jquery and jquery ui have come a ways since then.  Any who, can you post a fiddle of this so we can play around with it that uses the version of jquery and jquery ui you're using?

Comment: This looks like a more up-to-date equivalent : http://plugins.jquery.com/are-you-sure/

Comment: Aren't there browser related security issues that would actually require you to use the browser confirmation dialog?  I thought browsers could not be prevented from navigating through JavaScript except through the onbeforeunload event, which can only return a string.

Comment: Placing outside document ready (http://jsfiddle.net/salman/4c2xe/11/show/) or inside (http://jsfiddle.net/salman/4c2xe/12/show/) both seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can ***only*** popup a custom dialog if the user is trying to leave by clicking an anchor or other element *on your page*.

Then you could just intercept the click on all anchors etc, prevent it, pop up a custom dialog to confirm. In other words, when someone is clicking an element on your page, you're in control and can do pretty much whatever you want.

However, when the user is trying to leave by closing the tab or browser, you ***can not*** stop them with javascript, as it would be extraordinary annoying if websites could do that.

The only way to prompt a user that is leaving by closing the tab/browser window is to use the onbeforeunload event, and that event can ***only*** be used with the native confirm dialog, there is no way to use a custom dialog or stop the user or do anything else really, as that could lead to certain  websites creating systems where you could never really leave the site.

Answer (score 0):

From the README:

> Dirty Forms will alert a user when they attempt to leave a page without submitting a form they have entered data into. It alerts them in a modal popup box, and also **falls back to the browser's default onBeforeUnload handler for events outside the scope of the document** such as, *but not limited to*, page refreshes and browser navigation buttons.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

If you want to show a modal for this kind of things, well, you simply can't. (The reason why is security: it's easy to imagine a page preventing the user to close it whatever they attempt, short of killing the browser instance.)

Additionally, the "but not limited to" bit is intriguing: I would ask the plugin's author for details on what exactly this covers, as it might overlap with your use-case.